# Better way to manage authorisation for the same script running on multiple documents

Tags: google-apps-script

Users must edit multiple Google Docs and Sheets at intervals throughout the year. Once a user has finished their edit on a particular document, they must notify me (I am a Google Workspace super admin). I then move the document out of its folder and no users interact with it again.

Once a user has finished their edits, I would like them to click on a menu item called 'Finished Edits' that would then send the user and myself an email notification as well as appending 'Finished Edits - " to the start of the filename.

I have created a bound Google script that achieves everything I have described but the user is required to authorise the script whenever the menu item is clicked. I understand the need for security, but this is inelegant, annoying and some users would not be confident or have the knowlede to deal with this.

Is there a way for the user to allow the script on its first run and then remember the authorisation for the other documents? A bound script would have to be authorised each time, but would a library only need to be authorised once when used with multiple scripts? My attempts seem to indicate that it needs to be authorised each time.

Or is there a way a webapp, which runs under my permissions, that can be used like a library. I have looked at using using UrlFetchApp but can't figure out how to pass variables, such as the document ID.

Any advice would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

### Using Web app to Serve.

Based on your post, I have no clear information about your scope and definitive information about your current implementation. About the work around you are looking for. Yes, it is possible to serve your Google Apps Script through a Web App.

I understand that you are more inclined to do it that way and have issues with understanding how to pass variables over the HTML and your Code.gs. I have created sample code that will highlight this basic functionality of Web App.

### Code.gs:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function getDatafromHTML(name, description) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const rowData = [name, description];// Here is where I process the taken information.
  sheet.appendRow(rowData); // Write the values to the sheet.
}
```

### Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <form id="filloutForm">
    <label for="userEmail">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" id="userEmail" name="userEmail" required>
    <br>
    <label for="fileID">File ID:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fileID" name="fileID" required>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

  <script>
    document.getElementById('filloutForm').addEventListener('submit', submitForm);

      function submitForm(event) {
        var userEmail = document.getElementById('userEmail').value;
        var fileID = document.getElementById('fileID').value;

        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onFormSubmitted).getDatafromHTML(userEmail, fileID); // Here on this part of code is where I used the parameters to pass through variables to from HTML input filed to a Code.GS

        document.getElementById('filloutForm').reset();
      }

      function onFormSubmitted() {
        alert('File has been submitted ');
      }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Please take note that the purpose of the code is to highlight the "google.script.run.withSuccessHandler" but not to limit how you want to use it, you can also use it to trigger functions in your code so the user will not need Authorization but rather use the access granted to your Web App Script.

### References:

[Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)

[Create and Serve HTML](https://HTML%20Service:%20Create%20and%20Serve%20HTML)

Comment: @PerpetualD Great! Thank you for your response and confirming the understanding of my answer to your apps. Please feel free to  accept or upvote the answer if this help you so the community will know that their questions if they have the same as yours have answers and Please utilize the comment when going to reply to the answers you are looking out for.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response. The implementation is to allow managers to read and edit Google Docs and then notify me when they are complete using a menu item. The menu item would rename the file and send me an email. I would like to achieve this without having the authorisation dialogue to show on every of the large number of documents.

I am not experienced with Google Apps Script so I was hoping a Web App could get round this as it executes code using my credentials and not the user's. The bound script would have to send the document ID to the Web App so it could rename the document and send me the document ID in an email. In your code, the user has to enter the ID in a form manually rather than it being automatically sent from the Google Doc bound script.

If a web app cannot do this, is there another method that would work? For example, is there a way that a user could authenticate a library on first use and then not have to re-authenticate the same library when it is used in other Google Doc bound scripts? I am afraid I am at a loss. Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: As what you have discussed on your question it is part of the authentication work flow it means that it will be required everytime, the code I have showed you above is a basic of Web Apps and serving, what it highlights is actually sharing the authentication to the user that will access that web app, yes Web Apps can do what you are looking, it is a matter of playing around what is the implementation you are looking for. If the answer above help you, please accept or upvote the answer in this way the community will have the knowledge that their question same as yours have answers.

Comment: I understand from you response that there is no way to bypass the authentication when using a bound script on a Google Doc.

It would have been good for the managers to be able to stay within the Google Doc to initiate the notification email and the renaming of the filename. I will create a webapp that lists the documents ready for editing with buttons to open the document for editing and a button to indicate the editing has been completed (thus sending the email and renaming).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This could have been added as a comment than an answer